# Error in StatusText

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

in this line

```
<mx:Label x="132" y="105" id="statusText"/>
```

I get an error -

> Attempting to initialize inherited property 'statusText' of type
>   'spark.components.supportClasses.TextBase' with value of incompatible
>   type 'mx.controls.Label'.

Im using flex 4.6

Comment: What is the parent of Label?  It sounds like you're having an issue mixing Spark components with MX components; but it isn't clear to me what the issue is.

Comment: can you paste your full code?

Comment: xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[ if (fileReference.size > maxSize)
{statusText.text='File excedds max allowed';} else {
fileReference.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,uploadCompleteHandler);
fileReference.upload(urlRequest);
statusText.text="Uploading...";}}
private function uploadCompleteHandler(event:Event):void {
statusText.text="File Uploaded:"+event.target.name;}]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Label x="132" y="105" id="statusText"/>
<mx:Button x="132" click="uploadFile();" y="144" label="Upload"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you declare something in mxml with `id` which is already used in the superclass.
Normally it will just use your definition, overriding superclass one if it exists.

But in you code type of your definition for this id and superclass definition for this id are different, so you get this error.

As I see, it was not your intention to override superclass  definition, so you shall just *rename id* for your label.